# Plotting in a 'shiftlog' scale

Tags: plotting, ticks, transformation

I want to plot a function, whose natural behavior goes like

$$
f(x) \sim (x - a)^\alpha
$$

I.e. it's a power function, but with the argument shifted by $a < 0$. Thus, I feel like it's natural to plot this function in a "shift-log" scale; $\log (x - a)$ vs. $\log f (x)$.<sup>(1)</sup>

In other words, I want my horizontal axis $u$ to numerically go over real numbers (negative and positive), with mapping $u \to x = e^u + a$, but the labels on the axis should preserve the actual values represented by $x$, in a neat, logical, human-readable fashion. That is, for positive values, the axis should read powers like it does in a regular log plot. It should include 0 (if it's within the range). For negative numbers, it should read $a + 10^{-\text{power}}$.

For example:

- for $u = - \log(a)$, the axis should read 0 (i.e. zero is still a special value)
- for $u = -log (10)$, the axis should read $a + 10^{-1}$
- for $u = \log (10 - a)$, the axis should read $10$

Maybe even a better example is to explicitly give you something to plot. Let's take the following data:

```
a = -1/E;
f[x_] := 1/(x + a) + 1/x^2;
exampleData = N@Join[Table[{a + E^t, f[a + 10^t]}, {t, -15, -1, 0.2}], 
Table[{10^t, f[10^t]}, {t, -6, 4.5, 0.2}]];
```

we have a function that clearly has something interesting going on around $a = -1/e$, but also, point $x = 0$ is special (there should be a bump there).

Now we transform the example data (this is the transformation $x \to u$, which is already done for my data),

```
transformedData = Transpose@{Log[exampleData[[;; , 1]] - a], exampleData[[;; , 2]]};
```

Now I cook up the ticks, which should be generated automatically (but you can see explicitly how the tick mapping from $u$ to $x$ should work):

```
veryCustomTicks = 
  Join@ {{-Log[1000000], 
     "-1/e+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-6\)]\)"}, {-Log[10000], 
     "-1/e+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {-Log[100], 
     "-1/e+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-2\)]\)"}, {-1, 0},
     {Log[10 - a], "10"}, {Log[100 - a], 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(2\)]\)"}, {Log[1000 - a], 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)"}, {Log[10000 - a], 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)"}};
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {-Log[10^k], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, {1, 3, 5}}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {-Log[10000 k], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {-Log[1000 k], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {-Log[100 k], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {-Log[10 k], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {Log[k 1 - a], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 1, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {Log[k 10 - a], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {Log[k 100 - a], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {Log[k 1000 - a], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
Do[AppendTo[veryCustomTicks, {Log[k 10000 - a], "", {0.007, 0}}], {k, 2, 9}];
```

Finally the plot:

```
ListLogPlot[transformedData, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {veryCustomTicks, Automatic}}]
```

And it should look like this:
[image: Example plot]

**Question**: how do I achieve this, somewhat automatically? The amount of ticks, labels, etc. all depend on the range - whether the range goes below zero, how close it gets to $a$, how far it goes above zero etc. It should only display "nice" numbers (just like the regular ticking machinery does).

For simplicity, since my use case is always for $a = -1/e$, you can assume this value. The labels shouldn't fight, if the labels for $-1/e + 10^{-n}$ for each integer $n$ collide, the  algorithm should skip and do only odd or even $n$ (or skip even more, if needed). Just like in a log plot.

**Task**: given a range (either in $u$, such as (-10, 6), or in $x$, such as (-0.367834, 25118.9) - it's obvious that the "$u$" version is preferable), return automatically generated ticks in a "shiftlog" fashion to be aplicable to a plot whose axis was transformed by said shiftlog.

It might work with the `ScalingFunctions`, but I don't know how.

(1) I feel like a paragraph is needed here about numerical precision and why we try to avoid combining log scales with nonzero shifts; my data comes with a long double precision in both the "x"-values and "y"-values and the number shift $a$ is equal to $-1/e$, i.e. a number "of the order of 1. Given long double's amount of significant digits, I'm confident, that this shift does not cause troubles in a log scale, unless we go down to $10^{-16}$ or so (which we don't).